# Modelling growth of bacteria

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling

The logistic growth is in the form
 where the constant $r$ defines the growth rate and $K$ is the carrying capacity

$$
\frac{dP}{dt} = rP\left(1 - \frac{P}{K} \right)
$$

and Monod function is defined as

$$
\mu = \mu_\max \frac{S}{K_s + S}
$$

What’s the difference between a logistic function and a Monod type function? They both saturate at some level. Mathematically what is the difference between the two functions?

For example, [in this article](https://elifesciences.org/articles/10559) how is it decided that it is better to use Monod function than logistic growth as both can model the bacterial growth limited resource allocation.

$$
\frac{dB_s}{dt} = G_s B_s - k_pPB_s - k_i IB_s - \mu B_s
$$

Here $B$ refers to Bacteria and $G_s$ is modelled as $\lambda_s = \Lambda_s \frac{R}{k+R}$
Where $R$ represents resource and $\Lambda _s$ denote maximum bacterial growth rate in the absence of resource limitation.

But [in this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21300073) the bacterial growth is modelled as a logistic term

$$
\frac{dP}{dt} = rP\left(1 - \frac{P}{K_p} \right) - \frac{\gamma_{M_A}f(P,M_A^*)}{1 + k_dD M_A^*}M_A^*P - \gamma_N NP
$$

Is there a basis as to decide which form should be used?

Comment: "They both saturate at some level." Do they? The logistic does, but the Monod?

Comment: @Did Doesn't it saturate when $S\to \infty$ to $\mu_{max}$

Comment: Right, see some crucial differences in my post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** A logistic evolution $$P'(t)=rP(t)\left(1-\frac{P(t)}K\right)$$ predicts that, for every initial condition $0<P_0<K$, $P(t)$ grows from $P_0$ to $$P_\infty=K$$
**2.** On the other hand, experiences on bacterial growth led Monod to model the joint evolution of the concentrations of nutrient $S(t)$ and of bacteria $N(t)$ by the differential system $$N'(t)=\mu_\max N(t)\frac{S(t)}{K_s+S(t)}\qquad cS'(t)=-N'(t)$$ where $c>0$ is the growth yield. When $c$ is assumed constant, one gets $$N(t)=N_0+cS_0-cS(t)$$ hence $$N'(t)=\mu_\max N(t)\frac{cS_0+N_0-N(t)}{cK_s+cS_0+N_0-N(t)}$$ which predicts that $N(t)$ grows from $N(0)=N_0$ to $$N_\infty=N_0+cS_0$$
**3.** Thus, in the logistic model, the limiting quantity $P_\infty$ does not depend on its initial value $P_0$ but depends on the carrying capacity $K$, while, in Monod's model, the limiting quantity $N_\infty$ depends on its initial value $N_0$ but not on the analogue $K_s$ of the carrying capacity. This may help to discriminate these two classes of models.

Comment: So the two forms give the same behaviour but is it that when the carrying capacity is difficult to find the Monod function is better? Also in the article I found here https://math.la.asu.edu/~halsmith/bacteriagrow.pdf it is mentioned "Unlike the logistic equation the Monod equation give a clear mechanism for bacterial deceleration of the growth rate, namely nutrient depletion" I don't understand what is meant by this. Can you please help me to clarify it

Answer (score 0):

The first equation is a **differential** equation for P.  It's general solution is $P(t)= \frac{CKe^{rt}}{1+ Ce^{rt}}$ where "C" is any constant.  If we take S to be $Ce^{rt}$, that becomes $P(t)= \frac{KS}{1+ S}$ which is of the "monod" form.

Comment: But we do not "take $S$ to be $Ce^{rt}$"...